# Delete the files in current folder in the Linux based on the timestamp

Tags: linux

I want to delete the files in current folder in the Linux based on the timestamp. Using below commands I’m able to filter the files what I want delete, But cannot able to remove the files using rm/delete command, I tried in several ways like I’m using xargs rm command and delete command, non of them worked, please help me on this.

1. find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec ls -l {} + | grep ’00:00’
2. ls -l | grep ’00:00’

Comment: "I tried in several ways". Please show the command attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do the above but extract the paths to the files as well. The below will delete all your files that are found by the find command through time stamp provided

```
      rm -rf `find -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec ls -l {} + | grep '00:00' | awk '{ print $9 }'`
```

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this using various approach:-

1. Most Efficient Approach saves you from having to pipe everything through xargs, and having to handle filenames with spaces or other disruptive characters.

`find /path -type f -not -newermt "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS" -delete`

2)Since you found the files, You can touch your timestamp as a file and use that as a reference point, however, keep in mind it pollutes the filesystem with temp timestamp file.

e.g. for 01-Jan-2021:

```
touch -t 201401010000 /tmp/2021-Jan-01-0000

find /path -type f ! -newer /tmp/2021-Jan-01-0000 | xargs rm -rf
```

3)This will not pollute the filesystem with temp timestamp
`find /path ! -newermt "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" | xargs rm -rf`